# Is the only way of passing POST parameters in HTML through a form?

Tags: html, http, post, get

In HTML, you can send data from one page to another using a GET request in a couple of ways:

```
http://www.example.com/somepage.php?data=1
```

...or...

```
<form action="somepage.php" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="data" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

With a POST request though, I've only seen data being sent through form elements like this:

```
<form action="somepage.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="data" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If I only have one parameter I want to send to another page using POST, is there an easier way than wrapping it in a form?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are only two ways to POST from a browser - a form, or an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request.

Answer (score 7):

Using HTML only, a form is the only way to generate a POST request. You can use server side scripting / Javascript to generate POST requests in other ways, but no other ways to do with plain HTML only.

Answer (score 4):

As you've already discovered, there are exactly two ways to transmit data over the http protocol: `GET` or `POST`.  There is also a third type of HTTP message called `HEAD`, but that's really only used to get the meta data around a resource without downloading it and isn't widely implemented.

Obviously both `GET` and `POST` are easily accessible through the use of a `<form>` tag.  The `GET` is also easily accessible by manually adding query parameters to the URL in the form of name-value pairs (`foo.html?a=1&b=2`).

The beauty and complexity of the `POST`, however, is that the name-value pairs are communicated from the browser to the web server enclosed within the HTTP request header which is not as easily accessible.  The only way to accomplish the `POST` without using a `<form>` tag is to manually alter the HTTP request header and add the name-value pairs in yourself.

Also keep in mind that an HTTP server doesn't intrinsically know whether a request (`GET` or `POST`) came from a main browser window or an AJAX call.  Regardless, the web server will read the request, will decipher if it's a `GET` or `POST` request, look for name-value pairs as appropriate, and generate a response.

If you'd like additional detail on how to properly format a `POST` request you can go to [jmarshall.com/easy/http/](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/) or perhaps [tcpipguide.com/free/t_HTTPRequestMessageFormat.htm](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_HTTPRequestMessageFormat.htm).  The definitive resource is always the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html), but sometimes the RFCs can be terribly confusing for us mere mortals to read.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML only it's with a form.

But you can do it if you play with your server side. Here is a good article that show you how to manipulate the [Get to Change it to Post](http://www.zend.com/zend/spotlight/mimocsumissions.php#Heading6) via PHP. This will require you to play with  fsockopen... This way to do it will use your parameter ?id=1&param=2 ... and will create a POST request on the server side. You can make it generic, once it setups it will works, but it's a little work to setup everything first.

Comment: I think his intention was to create a POST request to avoid sending the parameters over the address line.. which your method defeats.

Comment: When I read his question I understand that he wants to send stuff within the url and not a form and proceed all via POST... but I might be wrong... question is unclear than... anyways what I suggest works if the OP want to do what I suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course always do a GET to a page which contains server-side (or AJAX) logic which will create a POST request (e.g. GET /pageWhichCreatesAPost.py). Very messy of course, but there can be cases where such a work-around could maybe be useful.

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote 1 hour ago :P